# Using youtubeEmbed-jQuery returns NoLongerAvailableException

Tags: javascript, youtube, gdata

I am running the following script as part of the youtubeEmbed-query-1.0.js plugin and since a short period this is returning an error 'NoLongerAvailableException'. I also can't find an update of the plugin.

```
    var youtubeAPI = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc';
    $.get(youtubeAPI,{'q':settings.videoID},function(response){

        var data = response.data;

        if(!data.totalItems || data.items[0].accessControl.embed!="allowed"){

            // If the video was not found, or embedding is not allowed;

            return elements.originalDIV;
        }
```

js fiddle example showing the error can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tL14auhe/1/

Comment: make a jsBin to test it.

Comment: update question with a link to jsfiddle

Comment: where? i can't see it.

Comment: Got it. But, where is the plugin file in the demo fiddle?

Comment: i just wanted to keep the question clean as the error is not due the plugin. I extracted only the relevant script found within the plugin

Comment: Undestand. But the problem is that YT does not support anymore the call, as mentioned below.

Comment: so there must be an alternative, right?

Answer (score 2):

Google has not yet supported an old version of YouTube API. You can find more information [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?hl=en).

Comment: Wont youtube api be supported in the future? from now on? iam especially interested in the gdata api.

Comment: The return of the response is 'No longer available': "{"apiVersion":"2.1","error":{"code":410,"message":"No longer available","errors":[{"domain":"GData","code":"NoLongerAvailableException","internalReason":"No longer available"}]}}"

Comment: Is there any known alternative?